# H5BP loading slow in IE

Tags: html5boilerplate

Has anyone experienced HTML5 Boilerplate loading super slow in IE? I'm building a site using it and everything is fine in FF, but when I try to open it in IE, it takes more than a minute to load.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the protocol-relative URL. You can find out more in the [HTML5 Boilerplate FAQ](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/25c1073d13eb49a948d7040525ba656d93aece30/doc/faq.md) for v4.0.1